# Primes of the form $a^k + b^k$

Tags: prime-numbers

How many primes are there of the form
$a^{k/2} + b^{k/2}$ exist for $a$ and $b$ (positive integer solutions).

I am hoping there is only one.

**EDIT** $k > 1$

Comment: If $k$ is odd and greater than $1$, there is none since $a+b$ divides $a^k + b^k$. And every prime of the form $4m+1$ can be expressed as a sum of two squares.

Comment: and if k is even?

Comment: If $a=2$ and $b=1$ there are known to be multiple solutions, the so-called _Fermat primes_.  If $a=2$ and $b=3$ then $k=1$, $k=2$ and $k=4$ all give solutions.

Comment: see edit please

Comment: What is meant by the initial equation (since right now the syntax is a bit messed-up)?  Can you give a good specific example?  (And explain why $2^2+3^2$ and $2^4+3^4$ both being prime doesn't contradict your hopes?)

Comment: @fosho Is your question "Given $a$ and $b$, how many primes are of the form $a^k + b^k$?" or "Given $k$, how many primes are of the form $a^k + b^k$?" or is it just "How many primes are of the form $a^k + b^k$"?

Comment: @Steve to the power of k/2, but i see both your examples work so back to the drawing board

Comment: im trying to prove that $$x^k + px = y^k$$ has only one solution

Comment: where p is prime and k>1

Comment: There are certainly more than 1: $13=2^2+3^2$ and $41=4^2+5^2$.

Comment: @fosho you might as well write $a^k+b^k$, since non-integer exponents can't produce rational results.  If you're trying to take into account that any $k\gt 1$ must be even (as Marvis notes) then you presumably want $a^{2k}+b^{2k}$ - but I wouldn't even bother with that; instead I would just write $a^k+b^k$ and note the implicit restriction on $k$ as an aside.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202247/number-of-solutions-to-equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infinitely many.  In fact, every prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ can be written as the sum of two squares; a result attributed to [Fermat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares).  And there are infinitely many such primes, according to [Dirichlet's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).